# Delete item from SQLite Database and update ListView

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, listview

I am trying to delete an item from a listview via a dialog menu. When an item is selected, I retrive the item's name and give an option to delete that item given the item's name. But when I try to delete and reload the listview (see picture). I get errors on SQL statements.

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mGJy.png

Here is the deleting method:

```
termList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        final String termName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_termName)).getText().toString();
        builder.show();
        builder.setAdapter(menAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String term = termName;
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        Context c = MainActivity.this;
                        Intent i = new Intent(c, CourseListActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("termName", term);
                        c.startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        db.delete("termTable", "name = " + term, null);
                        termListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the log file:

```
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Name": syntax error: , while compiling: DELETE FROM termTable WHERE name = Term Name: hello
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1759)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at com.dagonar.achievegpa.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:938)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1485)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2941)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3658)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 14:27:00.190: E/AndroidRuntime(26451):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
```

I hope you could help me find a solution.

Comment: probably you need to have column named Name, and the query must be "... Name='hello'.. " while you're getting text from TextView which is actually "TermName: hello"

Comment: the second line of the error clearly explains the problem. "Syntax Error". Check this tutorial on how to use sqllite with android http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your goal is to execute the following statement:

```
DELETE FROM termTable WHERE name = 'hello'
```

instead of:

```
DELETE FROM termTable WHERE name = Term Name: hello
```

So the correct code will be:

```
String term = termName.split(":")[1].trim();
switch (which) {
    case 0:
        Context c = MainActivity.this;
        Intent i = new Intent(c, CourseListActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("termName", term);
        c.startActivity(i);
        break;
    case 1:
        db.delete("termTable", "name = '" + term + "'", null);
        termListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And please split label and value into the 2 `TextViews`, don't put everything inside the one `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the term value as "Term Name: hello", what you need is 
db.delete("termTable", "name = " + "'+term+'", null);